# Nhibernate Delete 3

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Tried to delete using nhibernate, but got caught on a error like

> " 'tItemVantagem' is not mapped"

but it is. Any suggestions?

```
_session.Delete(string.Format("DELETE FROM tItemVantagem WHERE IdContraCheque in(select IdContraCheque from tContraCheque  where IdCompetencia ={0})", competencia));
_session.Delete(string.Format("DELETE FROM tItemDesconto WHERE IdContraCheque in(select IdContraCheque from tContraCheque  where IdCompetencia ={0})", competencia));
_session.Delete(string.Format("DELETE FROM tContraCheque WHERE IdCompetencia ={0}", competencia));
```

Here is the mapping :

```
public ItemVantagemMAP()
    {
        Table("tItemVantagem");
        Id(x => x.Identificador, c => { c.Generator(Generators.Identity); c.Column("IdItemVantagem"); });
        ManyToOne(x => x.TipoVantagem, y => { y.Cascade(Cascade.None); y.Update(false); y.Insert(false); y.Fetch(FetchKind.Join); y.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy); y.Column("IdTpItemVantagem"); });
        Property(x => x.HorasPercentual, y => { y.Column("QtHorasPercentual"); });
        Property(x => x.Valor, y => { y.Column("VlItemVantagem"); });
    }
```

Comment: Please show that it is mapped and what you have tried in order to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The `Delete()` method takes an HQL string which operates in terms of your mapped classes, not your table names.

From your mapping, `tItemVantagem` is the name of the table. I sincerely doubt that is the name or your mapped class (which you have oddly left out of the mapping you posted).